# How to programmatically modify an exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

I have an exposed filter on the Title field for my content type; i would like to use the same filter for applying the following condition: select all where (field_value) like %node.Title% OR %author.Title% where Author is a term reference to an Author vocabulary.
I've tried to do this but i wasn't able to solve it.
How can i do it? Have tried using views_query_alter but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should make a hook_form_alter to build only one box.

And in the validation or submit give the box value to both form_state options.

Another options is to use hook_query_alter to build your own query.

Oskar