# Views exposed filter to search multiple fields

Tags: 7, views, search

To my knowledge there hasn't been an option in drupal 7 to create a single exposed filter in a view which searches multiple fields, while in previous versions there existed modules to do just that.

Using the `or` operators is fine but then you get multiple fields in the form.

Add `Global: Populate filters` and you can have a single field but then the view never shows anything.

Is there any way or module that will make this work?

**Edit:** What I didn't notice was the field operators. For some reason the default operator for text fields in views is `=`, while a proper search function needs `contains` or `has word`. I've been looking for the reason I couldn't get it to work for almost 6 months now. Wow. What a pain. /facepalm

Comment: Much better answer here. This is core Views functionality...
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73731

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple fields search in a single exported filter using `Global: Populate filters` and [Views filter populate](http://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate) module.

Check [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/43762/2792).

Comment: I'm just going to mark this as the answer, but I thought I'd elaborate on what the actual problem turned out to be (I've been working on this for over 6 months, typical that I'd solve it myself less than half an hour after sticking it on stack)

Answer (score 12):

In Drupal 7, you can use

```
Global: Combine fields filter
```

to get the desired functionality. By using the same, you can select multiple fields on which you want to perform search.

Comment: Note that you need to add any fields you want to search as fields in the view - hide them if you don't want them to be displayed.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question has been answered already, but thought I'd chime in that there's another filter called "Search: Search terms" which basically emulates the Drupal node search and searches the whole node for the entered keywords. You can't select any fields to specifically search, and I'm not sure if it uses the "Search Index" view mode etc. But it works very well.

More info: http://drupal.org/node/680442

Comment: This is actually the easiest way to go, and it is fast too. Tried different approaches, this one is by far the best. Also described here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73731/how-do-you-combine-exposed-filter-string-text-searches-into-one-input-field-for