# Global Combine fields filter (Views) does not include Referenced Entities (Content Type)

Tags: views, entities

I have an Content type which contains another Content type, I managed to put in place the relationships using `Entity Reference` I also configured Views module to display the contained content type, the problem is when creating a Global Combine fields filter I can't search with the contained Content type, it always returns an empty result. 
Is something wrong with my approach ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Global Combine fields filter at the moment, see also the [feature request for the Entity reference module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2341485).

This is possible though with the [Views filters populate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate). You can use any field of a referenced entity or field collection of which you setup the relation with in your view.

Howto :

- Like the instructions on the module's page describe, first step is to
  add the fields you want to search on in an OR combination of filters.
  With Drupal6 that would have been by using the 'Views Or' module; with
  Drupal7 this is just a filter group with internal operator set to
  'Or'. These individual filters should  not be exposed.
- Then these filters can be exposed as one input by adding the module's provided filter called 'Populate filters', found on the 'Global' section. Expose it and check the filters you added in the Or group.

Comment: This is now possible.