# Views Autocomplete search multiple values

Tags: views, ajax

I'm trying to have a search filter that searches on 2 values and works with autocomplete list.

This is what I've done:

- Installed the module Views filters populate.
- added two filters "CNK" and "Naam" (both not exposed) and added them to a OR filter group. I used the operator "Contains any word" for both fields.
- Created a filter "Global: populate filters", added the two fields into this and exposed it.

My filter criteria looks like this:

[image]

But I don't have the option for autocomplete. How can I do this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Views autocomplete filter](https://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) module to have auto-complete feature on views exposed filters.

> It works for node titles or cck text fields.
>
> The autocomplete results are actually the view results, so they are
>   view related.

Check out this [Demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkyIYnYswko).

Comment: I'm using the views autocomplete filter but it doesn't work on the global: populate filters. It doesn't show the option autocomplete.

Comment: follow this post, :)

https://drupal.org/node/451000

Comment: and also this, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/expose-single-filter-of-combination-of-two-fields-in-views/43762#43762

Comment: I've done the steps in the last link you gave me (as you can see in my topic) but I don't have an autocomplete option on my global filter that selects the other 2 fields ... I need autocomplete on that field ..