# How to create custom search filter using view

Tags: 7, views

I am using [ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) module in site. I need to create search filter,that will be search product sku,title and description etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module helps you.

Comment: yes I am using this module.. but I need to search 3 values. sku, title and description.. So which filter value will have to use for this?

Comment: @jsh please check this [link](https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/views-exposed-filters-multiple-field-search). its explains how to create multiple field filter using views exposed filter.  i think this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple fields search in a single exported filter using Global: Populate filters and "Views filter populate" module.

Please, also, check this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/43762

Comment: I used it but its not working for me.