# View filter to include title and body text

Tags: 7, views

I created an exposed view filter so that users can search for words in the body of a node type but I would like the search to also look for words in the title without having a separate search box for titles. Can this easily be done?

[See code for exported view](https://pastebin.com/nyqL8U2t).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This module will help to do you job [**Views filters populate**](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate)

> This is an utility module. Its sole purpose is to fill in one blank
>   that seems not easy to be done using normal views, which is to use one
>   exposed string filter to search on multiple fields.
>
> Bear in mind, that, for now, only populates STRING exposed filters, so
>   those filters that take an array (options) or special types won't
>   work, although it may not be difficult to extend it.

You need to make use of `Global: Populate filters` or `Global: Combine fields filter` its explained in steps  [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/expose-single-filter-of-combination-of-two-fields-in-views/43762#43762)